# How to capture all regex occurrences (plus negation)

Tags: regex

I'm just trying a few examples and I'm kind of stuck with this one:

```
(&[^#|amp|quot|apos])
```

It's capturing an extra character after '&'.

```
a &a text with &amp; an &f and &#
```

Captures &a and &f.

How to capture & only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is negative look ahead. You can write it as

```
&(?!#|amp|quot|apos)
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sH2jR2/1)

**Regex Explanation**

- `&` Matches a single `&`
- `(?!#|amp|quot|apos)` Negative look ahead. Check if the `&` is ***not*** followed by `#` or `amp` or `quot` or `apos`.

---

**What is wrong with `(&[^#|amp|quot|apos])`**

- `[^#|amp|quot|apos]` This doesn't translate to `amp` or `quot` or `apos`. This is a character class which translate to `#` or `|` or `a` or `m` or `p` etc.